# Force Safari to recognize tabindex on anchor tags

Tags: jquery, safari, tabindex, jqtransform

**Background:** We are using a jQuery plugin, [jqTransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/) to skin our website. The problem is that jqTransform converts certain input elements into anchor tags, and Safari refuses to tab over anchor tabs. Illustrated below:

**Chrome:**
[image]

**Safari:**
[image]

**Question**: Is there a workaround to force Safari to tab over an element?

Comment: Maybe try to set tabindex attribute to these specific element. Now for getting more help, you need to provide some relevant code in question

Comment: Setting the tabindex doesn't fix the problem. And the code is at [the jqTransform website](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discussion thread here on [the official jqTransform GitHub](https://github.com/jcamenisch/jqTransform/issues/4) page. Initial report [from `helgatheviking`](https://github.com/jcamenisch/jqTransform/issues/4#issue-3012070):

> Radio, checkbox and select elements all ignore assigned tab-indices
>   once they've been transformed with the plugin, even though the
>   tax-indices are still in the markup according to firebug
>
> tabbing between text inputs and textareas is fine, but will skip over
>   any radios, checkboxes or selects.

Only advice seems to be to abandon jqTransform and move to something else. The user [`jcamenisch` reports](https://github.com/jcamenisch/jqTransform/issues/4#issuecomment-4823455):

> @helgatheviking, have you checked out [DropKick](https://github.com/JamieLottering/DropKick)? It looks like it
>   already supports tab index. I'm looking it over and considering
>   switching.